# How can I move from another screen to another with MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a screen to create records in MVC. If the model validates then I want to return back to my Home screen. I have seen the following:

```
                return new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new RouteValueDictionary(
                        new { controller = "Access", action = "Home" }
                    )
                );
```

This seems rather overkill as it specifies the controller and I don't want to change controllers. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default route looks like this in global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional},
);
```

That means that the `"Home"` controller will be used if none has been specified (as in `http://yoursite/`). The default action is `"Index"` (as in  `http://yoursite/somename/`).

**Redirect to site home page**

With this knowledge we can use `RedirectToRoute` to visit the home page of the site and the controller. Let's start with the controller:

```
return RedirectToRoute("Default");
```

**Redirect to default action of a controller**

If we want to get to the default action for a controller, we can either use the action name directly as in:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

or specify the controller in `RedirectToRoute`:

```
return RedirectToRoute("Default", new { controller = "somename" });
```

But that would generate duplicated code in each controller, so let's move the code to our `BaseController` instead:

```
public ActionResult RedirectToHome()
{
    return RedirectToRoute("Default", new { controller = RouteData.Values["controller"] });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName");
```

to redirect to another action in the same controller.